# Is it better to hash individual parts instead of hashing hashes of the individual part?

Tags: hash, sha

I have several byte arrays from which I have to calculate the SHA hash. Something like this:

```
(b1, b2, ..., bn) -> SHA hash
```

If I know instead hash the individual byte arrays and then calculate the SHA hash from this, does this have the same "security", or chance of a collision?

```
b1 -> H1,
b2 -> H2
(H1, H2) -> Final Hash
```

Or simpler asked: Which method is "better"? **

** I'm not sure how a should formulate this question (-:

Comment: Most APIs allow you to continue "updating" the hash with more input data. In this way, you don't need all of your data in one consecutive buffer to hash it. However, adding in existing hashes produces a different result. If you don't care about the difference then it is okay. It should provide similar output characteristics  (e.g. collision resistance, avalanche effect, etc.)

Comment: My question is more about the output characteristics. From you wording with "similiar" I guess they are not quite the same but in practicality it doesn't matter? We had a discussion in the team were one person claimed it has the same characteristics and I doubt that, but we both don't have the theoretical background.

Comment: The characteristics are inherent to the algorithm not to the use of it. It remembers me to the question "Is safer to encrypt twice?"

Comment: @MarcoA.Hernandez So, if I understand you correctly, you say that the chances of producing a collision is the same regardless ho big the initial "input pool" is? Lets say on of the SHA algorithms has a chance X to produce a collision, then this is the same, regardless how big the input is?

Comment: That's right. Chance of collision is related to the uniformity of the hash's distribution, the number of blocks you are hashing and with the output size. Pre-hashing your input or increasing its byte length won't change any of this parameters.